How to install lib, binary, header in tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/component-name/usr/local/include,bin,lib
When I want to have my headers, library or binary in /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/include then I do following in bb recipe:
FILES:${PN} += "/usr/local/*"
EXTRA_OECMAKE:append = " -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/usr/local'"

so I change CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. Package is built succesfully but there is difference in comparison when I install above in standard path /usr/include, /usr/bin, /usr/lib.
Library, binary and headers are not installed in
tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/component-name/usr/local/include
tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/component-name/usr/local/bin
tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/component-name/usr/local/lib

There is only:
tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/component-name/sysroot-providers/component-name

Other components with DEPENDS to above recipe don't have in their component sysroot binary, lib and headers as well so such components are not buildable.
Does anyone know what to add in recipe to install these stuff in tmp/sysroots-components?
Expanding this one:
FILES:${PN} += "/usr/local/*"

to absolute path with lib,bin,headers names also doesn't help. I feel like something is lack in recipe but I don't know what to do.
